# iOS5 - Limit allowsMultipleSelection

Tags: uitableview, selection, allowmultiple

I need to limit the number of multiple selection in a Table View, but I don't have any idea for where can I begin.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a NSMutableArray.  Whenever someone selects a cell, check the number of items already in the array.  If it's less than your limit, put a reference to that cell's backing data into your array.  If it has reached its limit, either ignore the selection or replace a previous selection...whichever makes sense for your app.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count > 5)
        return nil;
    else
        return indexPath;
}
```